# No protocol handler for Git+SSH while running helm

Tags: git, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I am trying to run a helmfile command on my local but I keep getting this error:

```
$ helmfile -f helmfiles/service-api.yaml -e qa diff
Adding repo transaction-api git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/helm-charts@service-api?ref=v1.2.8&sparse=0
in helmfiles/service-api.yaml: command "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\helm.exe" exited with non-zero status:

PATH:
  C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\helm.exe

ARGS:
  0: helm (4 bytes)
  1: repo (4 bytes)
  2: add (3 bytes)
  3: transaction-api (15 bytes)
  4: git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/helm-charts@service-api?ref=v1.2.8&sparse=0 (96 bytes)
  5: --force-update (14 bytes)

ERROR:
  exit status 1

EXIT STATUS
  1

STDERR:
  Error: could not find protocol handler for: git+ssh

COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: could not find protocol handler for: git+ssh
```

I have unisntalled and reinstalled helm and helmfile on my windows computer but still geting the error. Someone please help

Comment: The error message is coming from `helm`, not git itself, so the original version of this question only being tagged `git` wasn't particularly helpful. What version of helm is installed, specifically?

Comment: Are you using helm-git (from https://github.com/aslafy-z/helm-git)? If so, which _specific version_ of that tool did you install, and what steps did you use to install it? If not... why do you expect helm to support those URIs without it?

Comment: Hi Charles. Thanks for pointing that out. I’m using helm version 3.12.0 and helmfile version 0.153.1

Comment: That's the helm version, but do you have _any version of all_ of `helm-git` installed? (It's the plugin for helm that adds git support).

Comment: oh yes I do now. I installed version 0.15.1 but I'm now getting this error: STDERR:
  Error: looks like "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/helm-charts@service-api?ref=v1.2.8&sparse=0" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: exec: "C:\\Users\\first.last\\AppData\\Roaming\\helm\\plugins\\helm-git\\helm-git": file does not exist. That file exists in that location

Comment: Is it maybe named `helm-git.exe` instead of just `helm-git`? I could imagine that this is a bug in plugin support on Windows not adding the file extension (most Helm users don't use it on Windows, after all, and other/saner platforms don't use extensions for identifying executable types). If you were on a more UNIXy system I'd also look for dynamic linking problems, but if memory serves those present themselves a different way on Windows so it's probably not the immediate issue here.

Comment: Anyhow -- if that _is_ the problem, maybe you can edit the yaml file for the plugin to add the `.exe` extension?

Comment: This is what the plugin.yaml file on my local looks like:
name: "helm-git"
version: "0.15.1"
description: |-
  Get non-packaged Charts directly from Git.
downloaders:
- command: "helm-git"
  protocols:
    - "git+file"
    - "git+ssh"
    - "git+https"
    - "git+http"

I'm not sure where to add the .exe extension. Is it on the 'name' argument or the 'command' argument?

Comment: _If_ my interpretation above was correct (and to be clear, if I were 100% sure about it it would be an answer rather than a comment), you would add the `.exe` to the `command`.